# ERROR: Cannot match any routes URL Segment Angular 2

Tags: angular, mean-stack

I'm a relatively new developer and I'm having some trouble with a route that I've created within my MEAN stack application. Any help would be appreciated. I'm still learning, so not 100% sure if this is all of the relevant code, but let me know if I missed something that will be helpful in figuring this out. Thanks!

**Console Error when navigating to /createplan**

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'createplan'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'createplan'
    at ApplyRedirects.push../node_modules/@angular/router/fesm5/router.js.ApplyRedirects.noMatchError (router.js:1382)
    at CatchSubscriber.selector (router.js:1363)
    at CatchSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/catchError.js.CatchSubscriber.error (catchError.js:33)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._error (Subscriber.js:80)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.error (Subscriber.js:60)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._error (Subscriber.js:80)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.error (Subscriber.js:60)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._error (Subscriber.js:80)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.error (Subscriber.js:60)
    at TapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/tap.js.TapSubscriber._error (tap.js:61)
    at ApplyRedirects.push../node_modules/@angular/router/fesm5/router.js.ApplyRedirects.noMatchError (router.js:1382)
    at CatchSubscriber.selector (router.js:1363)
    at CatchSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/catchError.js.CatchSubscriber.error (catchError.js:33)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._error (Subscriber.js:80)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.error (Subscriber.js:60)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._error (Subscriber.js:80)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.error (Subscriber.js:60)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._error (Subscriber.js:80)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.error (Subscriber.js:60)
    at TapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/tap.js.TapSubscriber._error (tap.js:61)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:814)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:771)
    at zone.js:873
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:421)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:3816)
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:420)
    at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (zone.js:188)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:595)
```

**Routes: users.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const passport = require('passport');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const config = require('../config/database');
const User = require('../models/user');
const Plan = require('../models/plan');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

// Register
router.post('/register', (req, res, next) => {
    let newUser = new User({
        name: req.body.name,
        email: req.body.email,
        username: req.body.username,
        password: req.body.password
    });

    User.addUser(newUser, (err, user) => {
        if(err){
            res.json({success: false, msg: 'Failed to register user.'});
        } else {
            res.json({success: true, msg: 'User registered.'})
        }
    });
});

// Authenticate
router.post('/authenticate', (req, res, next) => {
    const username = req.body.username;
    const password = req.body.password;

    User.getUserByUsername(username, (err, user) => {
        if(err) throw err;
        if(!user){
            return res.json({success: false, msg: 'User not found.'});
        }

        User.comparePassword(password, user.password, (err, isMatch) => {
            if(err) throw err;
            if(isMatch){
                const token = jwt.sign({data: user}, config.secret, {
                expiresIn: 604800 // 1 week
                });﻿

                res.json({
                    success: true,
                    token: token,
                    user: {
                        id: user._id,
                        name: user.name,
                        username: user.username,
                        email: user.email
                    }
                });
            } else {
                return res.json({success: false, msg: 'Wrong password.'});
            }
        });
    });
});

// Profile
router.get('/profile', passport.authenticate('jwt', {session: false}), (req, res, next) => {
    res.json({user: req.user});
});

// Create Plan
router.post('/createplan', (req, res, next) => {
    let planMembers = req.body.members.split(",").map(item => item.trim());
    let newPlan = new Plan({
        id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
        name: req.body.name,
        description: req.body.description,
        begin_date: req.body.begin_date,
        end_date: req.body.end_date,
        members: planMembers
    });

    User.addPlan(newPlan, (err, plan) => {
        if(err){
            res.json({success: false, msg: 'Failed to create plan.'});
        } else {
            res.json({success: true, msg: 'Plan created.'})
        }
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router'; 
import { JwtModule } from '@auth0/angular-jwt';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NavbarComponent } from './components/navbar/navbar.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './components/login/login.component';
import { RegisterComponent } from './components/register/register.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './components/home/home.component';
import { DashboardComponent } from './components/dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { ProfileComponent } from './components/profile/profile.component';

import { ValidateService } from './services/validate.service';
import { AuthService } from './services/auth.service';
import { FlashMessagesModule, FlashMessagesService } from 'angular2-flash-messages';
import { AuthGuard } from './guards/auth.guard';
import { CreateplanComponent } from './components/createplan/createplan.component';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {path: '', component: HomeComponent},
  {path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent},
  {path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
  {path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent, canActivate:[AuthGuard]},
  {path: 'profile', component: ProfileComponent, canActivate:[AuthGuard]},
  {path: 'createplan', component: CreateplanComponent, canActivate:[AuthGuard]}
]

export function tokenGetter() {
  return localStorage.getItem('id_token');
}


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NavbarComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    RegisterComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    DashboardComponent,
    ProfileComponent,
    CreateplanComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes),
    FlashMessagesModule,
    JwtModule.forRoot({
      config: {
        tokenGetter: tokenGetter
      }
    })
  ],
  providers: [ValidateService, FlashMessagesService, AuthService, AuthGuard],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: add pathMatch: 'full' fro the first one: {path: '', component: HomeComponent, pathMatch: 'full'},

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first `''` route will be matching all routes, currently.

Try:
`{path: '', pathMatch: 'full', component: HomeComponent},`

I'm surprised you're getting that error though. I'd expect this just to route all paths to your HomeComponent.

Comment: Fixed that, but I still have the same error. :/ All of my routes have been working fine with this exception.

Comment: I've just noticed that it looks like you have a route `/createplan` in your angular routes and on (what I'm guessing is) your API for this app. Is this error occurring when navigating the angular client app or making a server `POST` request?

Comment: Just when navigating the app to the route. Haven't tried a `POST` request yet, seeing as this stopped me in my tracks a bit, but I will use Postman to try that out as well.

Comment: Tried out sending a `POST` request to the route and I got a 404 not found error. Hmm. Am I missing somewhere else where a route needs to be created within a MEAN stack application?

Comment: Your backend shouldnt affect it as angular will process the route first (personally I'd suggest you host your client and API on different base routes to keep your life simple!) - I made a simplified version of the Angular app on stackblitz - which works fine, try adding your logic piece by piece until it breaks https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jm3hv8

Comment: What does the code for the template and component you navigate from look like? You mention that this only occurs when you navigate.

Comment: @Steveland83 I basically just ran through a MEAN stack tutorial to create the foundation for this app and have been adding my own code on top of that to create a demo of a personal app project. Not completely sure how to go about hosting the backend and frontend separately like that. That aside, thanks for that I'll try integrating some of that code and report back!

Comment: @AndrewLobban I said navigate, but I meant that I'm just using the address bar to go to the route to test it out.

Comment: @DillonEstrada Angular version 2. Can you update what you currently have for your routes and screenshot of the browser? Also, is there a reason you aren't prefixing your API resources like with `/api`?